# How to debug system test using maven?

Tags: maven, testing, maven-3

I wrote a system tests (using junit), to test my work flows.
How I did run this is,

```
mvn clean install -Psystemtest
```

This will run all the systemtest, what I have. 
Now I wanted to debug only one systemtest at a time.

Is there any way to do this?

This is the 'failsafe-plugin'

```
<plugin>
 <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
 <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
 <executions>
 <execution>
 <id>failsafe-integration-tests</id>
 <phase>integration-test</phase>
 <goals>
 <goal>integration-test</goal>
 <goal>verify</goal>
 </goals>
 <configuration>
 <suiteXmlFiles>
 <suiteXmlFile>src/test/resources/systemtest-testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
 </suiteXmlFiles>
 </configuration>
 </execution>
 </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: depends, what maven plugin you use to run your tests. Could you tell us more on that? usually it would be surefire or failsafe maven plugin

Comment: Im using 'Apache Maven 3.0.4'

Comment: What do you mean by "debug" - do you mean, setting breakpoints and stepping thru the code? Then using an IDE might be better. If you meant to "execute" one test at a time, well that's a different question.

Comment: you still didn't provide answer to my first question, maven version itself is not so important here. Maybe pasting your pom.xml would help if you're not sure about plugin you use for testing.

Comment: Very sorry I use for this "junit" not testng 

    <dependency>
         <groupId>junit</groupId>
         <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
         <version>4.8.2</version>
         <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

Comment: @vikingsteve, Yes. I wanted to hit my brakpoints. I can run using IDE. but using this, some dependencies can not when running test. Because of that I need to use maven command to do this.

Comment: @darshakat which IDE are you using? I think your best bet is to get it configured properly in your IDE.

Comment: Have you tried following the information regarding debugging from the failsafe plugin website? Did any of that work?
http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/examples/debugging.html

Comment: I found a way to do this. Add cargo '-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8787' and start using -Dmaven.failsafe.debug  Thank you....